# Add multiple fields to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to add a function that generates multiple fields to my form.

This is how my form looks like:

```
<form action="form_sent.php" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
   <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>
   <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>
   <button>Add more fields</button><br><br>
   <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

In my case I want 3 new fields (name, phone, email) when clicking on "Add more fields".

How can I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/374cxt5s/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q8zj00s0/1/

**HTML**

```
<form action="form_sent.php" method="post">
  <ul id="fieldList">
    <li>
      <input name="name[]" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input name="phone[]" type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input name="email[]" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="addMore">Add more fields</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fieldList").append("<li>&nbsp;</li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Name' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='phone[]' placeholder='Phone' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='email[]' placeholder='E-Mail' /></li>");
  });
});
```

This allows you to store the results in array when you submit the form. Since you could have 5 names, phones, and emails, an array is the best way to address that. Then in PHP, you would have `$_POST['name'][0]` as the first one.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I wanted!!

Comment: Another way of doing it, using `fieldset` versus `ul`: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hn0oq5nn/1/

Comment: I used " $("#addMore").on('click', function(e) " to handle my click function before i could get the example to work.

Comment: @MesonraleOpeSeun was your `#addMore` button created dynamically? If so, that would explain why you had to bind the callback that way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you probably want to create a dynamic form that allows you to add multiple contacts, etc.

#### CodePen Example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVRgw

#### The Basic HTML Setup

So that you can loop through things, and for sake of your own sanity, you'll probably want to segment out each chunk within the form. We'll also set up a hidden input to track how many partitions of `name,phone,email` have been created. We'll default at `1`

```
<form action="form_sent.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="contacts" id="contacts" value="1">

    <div class="form-contacts-container">

        <div class="form-contact" id="form-contact-1">
            <input type="text" name="name-1" id="name-1" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" name="email-1" id="email-1" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="text" name="phone-1" id="phone-1" placeholder="Phone">
        </div>

        <!-- We'll be adding additional inputs here -->

    </div>

    <div class="form-contacts-add">
        <input type="button" value="Add More Fields" id="add-fields">
    </div>

    <div class="form-contacts-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

</form>
```

#### The JavaScript

This assumes you are using jQuery, so ensure that this is in your `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now we need to do a few things - firstly, attach an event listener to our `button` and secondly, add a new `<div class="form-contact">` with included fields to our form. We'll also need to ensure that we're counting up to make sure each section has a unique name/id, and we'll increase the hidden input value to count how many contacts have been added in total.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 1; // Our default for how many contacts we have


    $( document ).on( 'click', '#add-fields', function() {

        var addBlockId = total = total + 1;

        var addBlock = document.createElement('div');
        $(addBlock).addClass('form-contact');
        $(addBlock).attr('id','form-contact-' + addBlockId);

        var inputName = document.createElement('input');
        $(inputName).attr('type','text');
        $(inputName).attr('name','name-' + addBlockId);
        $(inputName).attr('id','name-' + addBlockId);
        $(inputName).attr('placeholder','Name');
        $(inputName).appendTo($(addBlock));

        var inputEmail = document.createElement('input');
        $(inputEmail).attr('type','text');
        $(inputEmail).attr('name','email-' + addBlockId);
        $(inputEmail).attr('id','email-' + addBlockId);
        $(inputEmail).attr('placeholder','E-mail');
        $(inputEmail).appendTo($(addBlock));

        var inputPhone = document.createElement('input');
        $(inputPhone).attr('type','text');
        $(inputPhone).attr('name','phone-' + addBlockId);
        $(inputPhone).attr('id','phone-' + addBlockId);
        $(inputPhone).attr('placeholder','Phone');
        $(inputPhone).appendTo($(addBlock));

        $(addBlock).appendTo($('.form-contacts-container'));
        $('#contacts').val(total);

    });

</script>
```

#### Processing your Form

The last piece of the puzzle is to process your form properly. Not goign to give you all the answers here, but the basic logic would be to grab the `$_POST['contacts']` value we've been updated and run a loop through to grab all of your inputs and associated values. For instance in `PHP`:

```
$total = $_POST['contacts'];
$contacts = array();

for( $i = 1; $i < $total; $i++ ) {
    $this_contact = $array(
        'Name'  => $_POST['name-' . $i],
        'Email' => $_POST['email-' . $i],
        'Phone' => $_POST['phone-' . $i]
    );
    array_push($contacts, $this_contact);
}

var_dump( $contacts );
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this :

```js
(function() {
   var button=document.getElementById("add-user");
   button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var cln = document.getElementsByClassName("user")[0].cloneNode(true);
      document.getElementById("users").insertBefore(cln,this);
      return false;
   });
})();
```

```html
<form id="users" action="form_sent.php" method="post">
 <div class="user">
   <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
   <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>
   <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>
 </div>
   <button id='add-user'>Add more fields</button><br><br>
   <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9955n4fo/

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! How can I add a name attribute to these fields when I want to validate them with php?

Comment: you can add them to a list by changing in HTML the initial input elements to have a names like : name="name[]" etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement jQuery to change the HTMLs DOM.

So, you add this in your `<head></head>` tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to modify your HTML like this:

```
<form action="form_sent.php" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
<input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>
<button extra="0">Add more fields</button><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you need to use this jQuery code:

```
<script>
$("button").on("click",function(){
var extra = $(this).attr("extra") + 1;
$("form").append("<input type='text' placeholder='Other Field' name='field' />");
$(this).attr("extra",extra);
}
</script>
```

This is the end!! :)

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a bad idea to wrap your input fields in a div just so when you append the other inputs they appear consecutively. Try something like this in your html

```
<form action="form_sent.php" method="post">
 <div id="fields">
   <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
 <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>
 <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>
 </div>
 <button>Add more fields</button><br><br>
 <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

and then your javascript can be completed as so

```
$(function() {  
$('button').click(function() { addFields(); });
});

function addFields() {
var html = "<input name='name' type='text' placeholder='Name'><br>
 <input name='phone' type='text' placeholder='Phone'><br>
 <input name='email' type='text' placeholder='E-Mail'><br><br>";

 $('#fields').append(html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The values from this form will get sent to an email. Is there a way to give them a name attribute so I could catch them maybe with an array?

Comment: @PomCanys yes, please see the answer I posted.

Comment: @PomCanys You can. @Twisty 's answer has that solution. You can edit the name attributes on the inputs so they have arrays like so. `<input name='name[]' />` Or you can use a counter in javascript and increase it with every click. Then simply attach that variable to the names in the inputs that you are generating in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :
Jquery append() function seems to sort out your answer
**HTML Code should be as follow :**

```
<form action="form_sent.php" method="post">
   <div class = 'xyz'>
   <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
   <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>
   <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>
   </div>
   <button>Add more fields</button><br><br>
   <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

you **JS** should be as follow :

```
$(button).click(function(event){
$('.xyz').append("<input type ='text' class ='name' placeholder = 'Enter name'/><br/>");
$('.xyz').append("<input type='text' class='phone' placeholder='Enter phone'/><br/>");
$('.xyz').append("<input type='mail' class='phone' placeholder='Enter e-mail'/><br/>");
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: As this will work, the result would be odd, as the new fields would be after the Submit button. Also you did not include the `<br />` that OP is using.

Comment: Posted an answer myself, since no one seems to address the array of name attributes being setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve it.

HTML:

```
<form action="form_sent.php" method="post">
   <div id="inputHolder">
     <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
     <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>
     <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>
   </div>

   <button id="addMoreFields">Add more fields</button><br><br>
   <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#addMoreFields").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $("#inputHolder").append('<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>');
        $("#inputHolder").append('<input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>');
        $("#inputHolder").append('<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r71odb7t/

Answer (score 0):

First you want to clone the elements you want to be adding. Do that when the page loads. Then when the button is clicked, clone the copy and add a copy to the page. And, you could either add `type="button"` to the button or use `e.preventDefault()` so your form does not get submitted when the button is clicked.

```js
$(function() {
    var inputs = $('form > button').prev().prev().prevUntil().clone().add('<br><br>');
    $('form > button').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).before(inputs.clone());
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="form_sent.php" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
   <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><br>
   <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail"><br><br>
   <button>Add more fields</button><br><br>
   <input type="submit">   
</form>
```