# Dynamically add dropdown fields and layout issue

Tags: jquery, html, contact-form

EDIT:

Thanks to `mohd afzal` it creates the dropdowns but I still have a few errors:

- The lay-out isn't exactly how it should be (see image)
- The second dropdown created doesn't respond after you've selected a value in the first.

[image]

---

I followed this, and it works, but gives me different problems. ([Add multiple fields to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532871/add-multiple-fields-to-form))

Current problems:

- I get input text fields instead of the dropdown menu's I created
- Messed up lay-out (see image)(I need the extra fields I get to be my dropdownboxes, and the amount field should be with the same code so the only numbers are allowed)
- **id and realName aren't shown in the images to prevent names to be shown**

[image]

Image of the form before clicking on 'add more'.

[image]

Used code:

**Jquery**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fieldList").append("<li>&nbsp;</li>");
        $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='ddl[]' placeholder='Choose a project' /></li>");
        $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='ddl2[]' placeholder='Choose a date' /></li>");
        $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='amount[]' placeholder='Amount' /></li>");
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="contact">
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
            Your personal card number
            <input type="text" name="card2" id="card" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" placeholder="Card Number" readonly/>
        </div>
        <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
            Your name
            <input type="text" name="name2" id="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['realName']; ?>" placeholder="Your name" readonly/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
            Order tickets for a project.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%" id="fieldList">
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <select name="ddl[]" id="ddl[]" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
                <option disabled selected>Select a project</option>
                <option value="Smile">Project Smile</option>
                <option value="Sand">Project Sand</option>
                <option value="Schmuck">Project Schmuck</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <select id="ddl2[]" name="ddl2[]">
                    <option disabled selected>Select a date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="2u 12u(narrower)">
            <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' name="amount[]" id="amount[]" value="" placeholder="Amount" />
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u">
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="4u 12u(mobilep)">   
            Total price.(In EUR)
            <input type="text" name="total2" id="total" value=""  readonly/>
        </div>

        <div class="row uniform">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions align-center">
                    <li><input type="submit" name="submit"value="Place Order"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're appending to `#fieldList`'s `li` element, which is not present (only the 'Place order' button is surrounded by an `li`). I'd say wrap the three div elements (*4u 12u narrower, 4u 12u narrower, 2u 12u narrower*) with a div called 'row-fields'. Then check uit jQuery's `clone` function to duplicate this div on click.

Answer (score 1):

You're appending to #fieldList's li element, which is not present (only the 'Place order' button is surrounded by an li). I'd say wrap the three input elements within a div and clone that div when needed.

Here is an example for you to perfectionize:

```js
var $addButton = $('#add-dynamic-field');
var $dynamicFields = $('#dynamic-fields').find('.dynamic-field');

$addButton.click(function() {
   // Clone the last '.dynamic-field' div and insert it
   $dynamicFields.last().clone().insertAfter($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" name="contact">
<div class="row uniform 50%" id="dynamic-fields">
    <div id="add-dynamic-field">Add a new field!</div>
    <div class="dynamic-field">
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <select name="ddl[]" id="ddl[]" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
                <option disabled selected>Select a project</option>
                <option value="Smile">Project Smile</option>
                <option value="Sand">Project Sand</option>
                <option value="Schmuck">Project Schmuck</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <select id="ddl2[]" name="ddl2[]">
                <option disabled selected>Select a date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="2u 12u(narrower)">
            <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' name="amount[]" id="amount[]" value="" placeholder="Amount" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="4u 12u(mobilep)">
    Total price.(In EUR)
    <input type="text" name="total2" id="total" value="" readonly/>
</div>
<div class="row uniform">
    <div class="12u">
        <ul class="actions align-center">
            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Order" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Weird, when I try it it doesn't work at all, but when I run the code snippet it does work :o And my 2nd dropdown menu doesn't listen to the first neither :s

Comment: Can't edit previous comment... I managed to get the 2nd dropdown to listen :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="contact">

    <div class="row uniform 50%">
        <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
            Order tickets for a project.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%" id="fieldList">
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <select name="ddl10" id="ddl10" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl20'))">
                <option disabled selected>Select a project</option>
                <option value="Smile">Project Smile</option>
                <option value="Sand">Project Sand</option>
                <option value="Schmuck">Project Schmuck</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="4u 12u(narrower)">
            <select id="ddl20" name="ddl20">
                    <option disabled selected>Select a date</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="2u 12u(narrower)">
            <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' name="amount0" id="amount0" value="" placeholder="Amount" />
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type='button' id='addMore' value='Add more'>
        <div class="4u 12u(mobilep)">   
            Total price.(In EUR)
            <input type="text" name="total0" id="total0" value=""  readonly/>
        </div>

        <div class="row uniform">
            <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions align-center">
                    <li><input type="submit" name="submit"value="Place Order"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>













 $(function() {
          var count=0;
          $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              count=count+1;
              $("#fieldList").append("<li>&nbsp;</li>");
              $("#fieldList").append("<li>"
              +"<select name='ddl1" + count + "' id='ddl1" + count + "' >"
              +'<option>Select a project</option>'
              +'<option value="Smile">Project Smile</option><option value="Sand">Project Sand</option>'
              +'<option value="Schmuck">Project Schmuck</option></select>'
              +'</li>');

              $("#fieldList").append("<li>"
              +"<select id='ddl2" + count + "' name='ddl2" + count + "'>"
              +'<option>Select a date</option></select>'
              +"</li>");
              $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='amount" + count + "' placeholder='Amount' /></li>");
          });
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I do get a few error: `lay-out is still not doing what is should do` and `the second dropdown it creates doesn't fill in itself after I've selected a value in the first one.`(I'll add a picture for you to see in the post)

Comment: 1)Actually i am forgot to use the onchange event on the dropdownlist ,you can just use those thing on the dropdounlist like that                                  + "<select name='ddl1" + count + "' id='ddl1" + count + "' onchange='configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2" + count + "'))' >"                                                                                                         2) the laout may be show differently due the design isses.